# How to implement typesafe domain repository in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, dotty, scala-3

I want to implement generic and typesafe domain repository. Say I have

```
trait Repo[Value] {
  def put(value: Value): Unit
}

case class IntRepo extends Repo[Int] {
  override def put(value: Int): Unit = ???
}

case class StringRepo extends Repo[String] {
  override def put(value: String): Unit = ???
}

case class DomainRepo(intRepo: IntRepo, stringRepo: StringRepo) {
  def putAll[?](values: ?*): Unit // what type should be here?
}
```

As result I want to have following api:

```
domainRepo.putAll(1, 2, 3, "foo", "bar") //Should work
domainRepo.putAll(1, 2, true, "foo") // should not compile because of boolean value
```

The question is How to achieve this?

so, I see only one way to make it typesafe. It's to do pattern matching on Any type like

```
def putAll(values: Seq[Any]) => Unit = values.foreach {
  case str: String => stringRepo.put(str)
  case int: Int => intRepo.put(int)
  case _ => throw RuntimeException // Ha-Ha
}
```

but what if I would have 10000 of types here? it would be a mess!

another not clear for me approach for now is to use dotty type | (or) like following:

```
type T = Int | String | 10000 other types // wouldn't be a mess?

def putAll(t: T*)(implicit r1: Repo[Int], r2: Repo[String] ...) {
  val myTargetRepo = implicitly[Repo[T]] // would not work
}
```

so, what do you think? is it even possible?

the easies way I've saw was

```
Map[Class[_], Repo[_]]
```

but this way allows to do a lot of errors

Comment: I haven't figured out the main idea of this. I heed to mutateAll(values: Seq[Int | String]), I want to mutateAll(1, 2, "foo", "bar")

Comment: most likely you will not be able to solve this problem as you expected using types and here is the reason: typeclasses and types in general present in compile time only, so compiler should know about type of your `t:T*` at compile time to understand what typeclass to use. In your case `t` parameter is an array containing values with types that can be calculated in runtime (depends on some external data for example), so compiler have no ideas what typeclass to use because it's out of the scope of compiler duties at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a type class

```
trait Repo[Value] {
  def put(value: Value): Unit
}

implicit val intRepo: Repo[Int] = new Repo[Int] {
  override def put(value: Int): Unit = ???
}

implicit val stringRepo: Repo[String] = new Repo[String] {
  override def put(value: String): Unit = ???
}

case object DomainRepo {
  def putAll[Value](value: Value)(implicit repo: Repo[Value]): Unit = repo.put(value)
}
```

---

If you want `domainRepo.putAll(1, 2, 3, "foo", "bar")` to compile and `domainRepo.putAll(1, 2, true, "foo")` not to compile, you can try to use heterogeneous collection (`HList`).

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, ::, Poly1}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper

trait Repo[Value] {
  def put(value: Value): Unit
}

implicit val intRepo: Repo[Int] = new Repo[Int] {
  override def put(value: Int): Unit = ???
}

implicit val stringRepo: Repo[String] = new Repo[String] {
  override def put(value: String): Unit = ???
}

case object DomainRepo {
  def put[Value](value: Value)(implicit repo: Repo[Value]): Unit = repo.put(value)

  object putPoly extends Poly1 {
    implicit def cse[Value: Repo]: Case.Aux[Value, Unit] = at(put(_))
  }

  def putAll[Values <: HList](values: Values)(implicit 
    mapper: Mapper[putPoly.type, Values]): Unit = mapper(values)
}

DomainRepo.putAll(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: "foo" :: "bar" :: HNil)
//  DomainRepo.putAll(1 :: 2 :: true :: "foo" :: HNil) // doesn't compile
```

Comment: I guess the better name for trait instead of `Repo` would be something like `RepositoryItem`(or something similar). So you've got object `DomainRepo` which can `put` types, which have an instance of `RepositoryItem` in scope.

Comment: See please clarified question. I've edited. The main idea is that putAll should take sequence of various types in that case sequence of ints or strings.

Comment: @IgorYudnikov You can try to use heterogeneous collection. See update.

Comment: @IgorYudnikov Please pay attention to BogdanVakulenko's comment to your question above. This approach works only if you know types at compile time.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Thanks. I guess TS can choose proper names.

Comment: @IgorYudnikov Maybe instead of `putAll` use `put` with fluent API?
`domainRepo.put(1).put(2).put("foo")`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Currently it's not about naming. It's not clear if TS knows types at compile time or only at runtime.

Comment: I just added it as an alternative for using `HList`. If he puts one element at a time, then typeclass could be resolved for that element.